# I can't understand the logic of this program

Tags: python-3.x

This is a program to determine the end time of a period of time.

```
hour = int(input("Starting time (hours): "))
mins = int(input("Starting time (minutes): "))
dura = int(input("Event duration (minutes): "))
mins = mins + dura # find a total of all minutes
hour = hour + mins // 60 # find a number of hours hidden in minutes and update the hour
mins = mins % 60 # correct minutes to fall in the (0..59) range
hour = hour % 24 # correct hours to fall in the (0..23) range
print(hour, ":", mins, sep='')
```

Comment: what do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the numbers entered are: 9 (start hours), 30 (start minutes) and 95 (duration).

First this `mins = mins + dura` produces 125. So the event ends 125 minutes after start hours 9. Now you want to know what time it is 125 minutes after 9:00.

This `hour = hour + mins // 60` adds the amount of full hours to 9:00. So how many times 60 fits fully into the minutes. In this case `hour = 9 + 125 // 60` results in 11 (the existing 9 + the two times 60 fits fully into 125).

Then this `mins = mins % 60` removes anything that fits into 60 minutes blocks, so the rest when dividing by 60. In this case 5.

Lastly this `hour = hour % 24` rounds down in case from the calculation we went over 23. E.g. if the event starts at 23:00 and goes for 120 minutes we would end up at 25 which is not a correct time, so we divide it by 24 and take the rest (1). In our case this doesnt do anything because 11 is smaller than 24.

Which gives us the result of 11:05 which is then printed in the last line of code.